# How to add touch screen functionality(tap left/right side of screen) in HTML5 mobile game?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, touch-event

I'm currently developing Doodle Jump game as a mobile web game using Javascript and HTML.

User need to hold the right side of the screen to move the Doodle to the right and hold left to move the Doodle to the left

Here I provide an image reference

[image]

1. How can I add invisible collider for both right and left side of screen?(Should I use HTML canvas or Javascript)
2. How to code the Eventlistener function in Javascript so that the player able to move the doodle by touching the left or right side of the mobile screen

Comment: this might help you: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, it's pretty easy to capture clicks on the screen.

Here is a fiddle that will do just what you are asking.

The click function will measure the width of the div and then compare the x location of the click to see if it is more or less than halfway across the div.

https://jsfiddle.net/q82nhef0/

```
$("#thediv").click(function(e) {
    var divWidth = $("#thediv").width();        
    var clickX = e.clientX;
    if (clickX > divWidth/2) {
        console.log("Div was clicked on the right");
    } else {
        console.log("Div was clicked on the left");
    }
});
```

This will work if you are using an html5 canvas. If you are building the play field with a combination of html5 elements, then I would suggest placing a div over the entire play surface, and this div should have a high z-index.